# catastrophic error: cannot open source file "stdlib.h"

Tags: c++, macos, icc

When compiling a C++ project, I have recently begun to see the following error:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/stdlib.h(94): catastrophic error: cannot open source file "stdlib.h"
#include_next <stdlib.h>
```

This is very strange because the offending line `#include_next <stdlib.h>` is within the file `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/stdlib.h` meaning the file is somehow trying to include itself and failing.

This is a default system file so I don't understand why it should be broken suddenly. And advice would be greatly appreciated.

(Running on macOS Mojave with Intel icpc compiler)

Comment: Is icpc picking up the command line tools from XCode properly (if you installed them)?

Comment: Show 10 lines around 94

Comment: Xcode command line tools are installed. The offending file is a part thereof.

Comment: The lines around 94 are as follows:
    #if !defined(_LIBCPP_HAS_NO_PRAGMA_SYSTEM_HEADER)
    #pragma GCC system_header
    #endif
    
    #include_next <stdlib.h>
    
    #ifdef __cplusplus
    
    extern "C++" {

Comment: Does it work if you include the C++ version of that file, `#include <cstdlib>`?

Comment: That's badly formatted but not sure how to change it in a comment.

Comment: The full trace shows that `stdlib.h` is being called from `cstdlib`

Comment: Perhaps `icpc` does not honor the (I presume) `clang` mechanism (mimics the `gcc` mechanism) for chaining include files.

Comment: It should go up to /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/, not v1

Comment: I think the intent of that line is to include the XCode header, which should be at `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include`.

Comment: Is your version of ICPC compatible with Mojave?

Comment: I've found a solution. Will post an answer to my question. Thanks for the input all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem was eventually solved by running the `macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg` installer located at `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages`

Comment: On Big Sur, this directory does not exist.  I had to use the other answer listed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65234342/3250829

Answer (score 2):

The following command helped me on MacOSX Big Sur: `export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/`

Comment: This was the answer that worked for me - confirmed that it works on Big Sur 11.6.1.  Thanks!